# difference between action="." and action=" "

Tags: php, html

Sorry if my question is basic. I have seen the code below on a tutorial for uploading a file. It uses `action ="."`, I know `action=" "` means page to itself but I do not know what means `action ="."`.

Another question is it uses:

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="upload">
```

I would like to know what does input `type="hidden"` and, is there relation between action attribute in form and value of name attribute in input.

```
<form id="upload_form" action="." method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="upload">
    <input type="file" name="file1"><br>
    <input id="upload_button" type="submit" value="Upload">

------------------------------------------------

switch ($action) {
    case 'upload':
...}
```

Comment: Hidden means you you can't see the input field on the page. It will just submit with the form.

Comment: Then when you submit the form you will get `$_POST['action'] => upload` the `$_FILES` array. The action is just telling the application to trigger that script

Comment: You should ask one question at a time, not several at once.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There is **no** difference between `action="."` and `action=""`. Either will redirect you to the current page *if* your URL **ends in "/"**. Otherwise not.

The element having the attribute `type="hidden"` is simply a supplementary input element that is **hidden**, which can have a value to be passed when submitting the form.

Comment: This is wrong. There is no difference ***iif*** the URL ends in a `/`. There very well is a difference if the URL ends in, for example, `foo/bar.html`.

Comment: Ah got it. I was testing it and didn't realize I was rewriting my URL. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

An empty `action` attribute resolves to the current URL as is.
The relative URL `.` resolves to the current parent path segment.

For example, if the URL is `.../foo/bar.html`, these are the results:

- `""` → `.../foo/bar.html`
- `"."` → `.../foo/`

If the URL ends in a `/`, like `.../foo/`, then both are equivalent.

Comment: on the sample tutorial i have, is like (.../foo/bar.html), i changed action ="." to action " " it works like before. is it possible explain difference with a simple sample